# Excluding system-wide packages in a virtualenv in PyCharm

Tags: python, virtualenv, pycharm

I created a virtualenv. Here are the third-party packages I installed.

```
(zhihu-py3)
laike9m@laike9m  ~/D/P/E/z/zhihu-py3   master 
❯ pip freeze                                                                                                                       
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
html2text==2015.6.21
requests==2.8.1
zhihu-py3==0.2.5
```

However, when I go to the "Project Interpreter" page in PyCharm, it lists all packages I installed systemwide, which is really annoying.

[image]

How could I make those packages not displayed? I only want to see the ones installed in this specific virtualenv.

**Edit**
While the `--no-site-packages` argument works for Python2, it does not work if I created a virtualenv using Python3

I recreated this virtualenv with `--no-site-packages` arguemnt:

```
(zhihu-py3)
laike9m@laike9m  ~/D/P/E/zhihu-py3 
❯ pip freeze                                                                                                          
wheel==0.24.0
```

Note that `no-global-site-packages.txt` does exist.

```
laike9m@laike9m  ~/D/P/E/zhihu-py3 
❯ ll lib/python3.5/ | grep no-gl                                                                                                    
-rw-r--r--   1 laike9m  staff      0 Oct 21 15:03 no-global-site-packages.txt
```

But still, PyCharm loads all packages from systemwide.
[image]

I tried removing paths from Pycharm's "Interpreter Paths" setting. It just shows "removed by user" but **never really removed those paths**.

[image]

Now I suspect this is a bug of PyCharm.

Some other imformation:
System: **OS X 10.10.5**
PyCharm version: **4.5.4**
Python3.5 is installed via homebrew in location: **/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/**

**Edit2**
PyCharm support team says:

> PyCharm uses sys.path which is wrong for you. As you can see, it works with 2.7 version, so the problem is specific to Python, not PyCharm.
>
> Someone from Python community will help you. It's not specific to PyCharm.

Comment: Have you tried creating virtualenv from commandl line using `virtualenv --no-site-packages my-venv-folder`? Totally guess and no idea if relevant at all.

Comment: No I didn't. Guess that's the reason.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I tested it, it surely works. You could post an answer and I'll accept. BTW do you know how to goto the "no site-packages" state given an already created virtualenv?

Comment: Virtual environments are not meant to be repaired but rebuild. So just created from a scratch. Do `pip freeze` and hand pick packages from the list for `requirements.txt` for pip installation.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Does "created from a scratch" mean "created in terminal"? If so, that's what I did.

Comment: So what was wrong with your `sys.path`? @laike9m

Comment: @bariod Sorry, I don't remember, it's been 3 years...

Comment: @laike9m no worries, was worth a try :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create virtualenv from command line using `virtualenv --no-site-packages my-venv-folder`. This way packages already installed in system-wide Python installation (`site-packages`) are not reflected inside the virtual environment.

Comment: It does not work for Python3 on Mac. I don't know why.

Comment: With python3 you may have to add the ` -p /usr/bin/python3 ` option to the `virtualenv` command (use the path relevant to your machine)

Comment: Also if you use Homebrew you can use `virtualenv3.4` command.

Comment: @stellasia I know, and I did add `-p pathtopython3`.

Comment: @laike9m: Can you edit the question and add related OSX errors?

Comment: You mean I should state this problem is OSX specific?

Comment: If you run `pip -p python3.5 -r requirements.txt` I need to see the error message if it doesn't work.

Comment: That's the underlying tool which must be working, because *every* Python developer is using it. If PyCharm doesn't work then you have done correctly and taken the problem to PyCharm support.